# return an arraylist from one jsp to another and give the json view

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have two jsp files,one is `query.jsp` and the other is `b.jsp`.In b.jsp i have connected a database,selected all values from database table `testemployee` and made an arraylist `rows` of all values inside `public List select()` function then returned the list.In `query.jsp` i tried to make the json format of that list calling select function of `b.jsp`

```
  <% Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(select());    %>
```

but it is not showing the json format of the database values.When i wrote

> `<%=select() %>`

it was showing the database values list perfectly.How should i solve it?Please consider my question.

my code 
  query.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>

<%@include file="b.jsp"%>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2><%
          Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(select()); 
  // select()      
    %>

    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

b.jsp

```
<%!
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
      String query;
%>
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "root");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
%>
<%!
  public List select() {
    List rows = new ArrayList();
    Map row = null;


    try {
        query="select * from testemployee";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            row = new HashMap();
            for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                row.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }

        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return rows;
}
%>​
```

i have imported all necessary files and also included `b.jsp` in `query.jsp`

Comment: Avoid using JSP pages for business logic

Answer (score 0):

<%= [select()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html) %> is an expression that converts whatever on the right part to a `String`, in this case the output of `select method` which is a List.

- `select()` is a java method not a function

So in order to to view your list you need to iterate over it  and draw it in a table, which means `HTML` otherwise you will be just executin a java method.

Here is an [example](http://www.jsptut.com/mixing.jsp).

**EDIT :**

```
<body>
    <h2><%
          Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(select()); 
  // select()      
    %>
    <%=json%>
    </h2>
</body>
```

Comment: but i wanted to get the json view of my arraylist without table for my project is there any other optin from which i can get the json object

Comment: @Sarah5 , you can just print `json` string - <%= json %>